# What means this part of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

please i need to know what means this part of code, i couldn't especially  understand the condition

```
var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}
```

Comment: It checks whether `define` is a function and has a non-falsy property named `amd`.

Comment: What specially do you not understand?

Comment: This looks alot like *require.js* to me. http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

If RequireJS is defined(1) then `classie` is registered with it. Otherwise it is placed on the global object (`window`).

Library authors sometimes put this kind of code at the bottom of their libraries to make them work seamlessly with whatever runtime environment they find themselves within (in this case RequireJS, with a fallback to using the global object).

(1) What it actually does:

The `typeof` operator is used to test for the type of `define` as a value available in the current lexical environment. `typeof` is used because it is the only operator to not throw an error when used with undeclared values.

The `define.amd` check (precisely: the value referred to by the `amd` property reference on `define` coerces to a truthy value) gives extra confidence that this is actually RequireJS and not some user defined object.

Comment: It's not me, I upvoted for the edit, but I'd suggest plus one edit: the if clause condition expects the type of `define` to be `'function'`, not 'as a property', but it's right

Comment: `typeof define` is testing for the presence of `define` "on the global object". Variables defined in the global context (in this case `define`) end up being properties on the global object.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but you didn't confirm that it tests if it's a function. And a property may have the `undefined` value, anyways.

Comment: I did: "The typeof operator is used to test for the presence *and type...*"

Comment: But it's wrong, it doesn't confirm it's testing if the property type is a function. I know much about ECMAScript and I'm just 15 years old. That's not how we check the presence of an object property, it'll fail for `undefined` values, and will also fail for getters and setters. If you want to mention 'presence' there should be a native operation like binary `in` or `Object#hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: It isn't wrong. It's absolutely correct AFAIK. It is less explicit than you would like. Meh, its my answer.

Comment: You don't agree, but I'm okay. We're discussing small concepts because you don't understand me.

Comment: Just as an aside, classes and bindings defined with `const` and `let` do not become properties of the global object.

Comment: @FelixKling Please can you help me rewrite "The `typeof` operator is used to test for the presence and type of `define` as a value present in the global lexical environment." to be exactly correct?

Comment: @BenAston: I think what you have sounds good. I might drop the global environment part since `typeof` really checks the *current* environment (which is always contained in the global environment of course). I.e. `typeof` checks for the presence (existence?) and the value of `define`.

Comment: I know much more than everyone here. Someone upvoted a <s>stupid</s> simple comment saying 'variables defined in the global context goes to the global object as properties', this is obvious, but not complete. I already know much more than that, *beyond*. I'm having to be rude to tell the truth...

Comment: If you are so knowledgable and this answer is so wrong, write your own answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use AMD. I know much *bit* (not sure if I spoke right; English isn't my primary language) about it.

Comment: I want to correct *value present in the current lexical environment.* again, this is NOT how variable presence is checked. `typeof` will fail for `undefined` values -_- (can't understand me...?).

Comment: OK - define fail? Return false? I agree. `(typeof undefined === 'function') === false`

Comment: No, I'm saying that it's not how a variable presence is checked. E.g., a variable will contain any value, even `undefined`. `typeof variable !== 'undefined'` isn't enough to check variable presence (it can be declared, initialized and assigned with ANY value, EVEN `undefined`), that's what I'm saying.

Comment: To really check if a variable exists or not (cross-browser solution, works for both global and local variables): `try { return ExpressVariableIdentifier, true } catch (\u{41}) { return false }`

Comment: This cross-browser test could be more customized with `eval` (better use `eval` than Function# because it evaluates the requested code in the same scope where it got called): `exists = IdentifierName => { try { return eval(IdentifierName), true } catch(\u{41}\u0042) { return false } };`

Comment: These tests will check if the variable is declared independently of any value. Much better. That's why `typeof` will fail.

Comment: @FREEZE: I think you interpreted too much in Ben's words. `typeof define === 'function'` returns `false` if a) The variable is not declared (presence test) and b) it's value is not a function (type test). You are right that in general `typeof foo === 'undefined'` is true if the variable doesn't exist or if it does exist and has the value `undefined`, but context matters. It's usually not necessary to distinguish between those two use cases. Furthermore when testing for the *existence* of a (global) variable, one usually expects it have a specific value (such as a function here).

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but in Ben's case he didn't advice that the return of unary `typeof` is being checked for 'function', he only said it's checking the presence of `define`.

Comment: I think this was a case of lost in translation. FREEZE was correct, but there was actually more than one way to interpret the relevant sentence in my answer. Let's put this convo to rest. I have remove the word "presence".

Answer (score 0):

This looks alot like *require.js* to me.

> http://requirejs.org/

In that case the condition checks whether require.js's `define` function is available and has a non-falsy property named `amd` to make your object `classie` available as a *module*, otherwise it will make it available *globally* (at least in the browser context) by attaching it to the **global object** `window`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no it's not from require.js is juste a code from codrops SlidingHeaderLayout created by Mary Lou .. please if you can explain to me: "define function is available and has a non-falsy property named amd to make your object classie available as a module"

Comment: The check if require.js is present is only to provide compatibility with environments in which the developers decided to use a modular approach for coding (AMD *A*synchronous *M*odule *Definition*). Explaining that approach here is far too much. There's loads of books on that.

Comment: Yes, I understood now why the developper put this code .. i will read more about require.js .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This small condition makes it possible to export your library (I'm not sure if it's a library, but it doesn't matter if it's) between AMD modules (I know almost nothing about require.js since I don't use it) and the global JavaScript object.

I'm mostly going to answer this because I want to correct @BenAston. Let's check the condition better:

```
// typeof is special with an unique identifier argument,
// however it's not truth that it's made to check if a variable
// is declared (since its value type can be any).

// Since typeof is special with identifiers, independently of strict mode
// it doesn't throw exceptions for non-existent variables (identifiers...).

If IsTruth (

    IsTruth(
    (UnaryTypeOf(Identifier define) Strict—Is 'function') And

    // Now check if define.amd getter returns a truth value.
    IsTruth(
        Get(Identifier define, '\u{64}md')
    ))

    CONSEQUENT: Define running script module with classie (AMD case)
        (Note that I'm not sure if that's what AMD does, I don't use it).
```

If that condition isn't the case, your script ends up running `window.classie` setter, with a reference to the hoisted `classie`.

My custom way (that I don't need to write again because I use webpack) to do the equivalent in a more universal way is (I recommend using webpack for this):

```
// Note: global object could be 'self' instead of 'this', not sure if
// all JavaScript based-platforms support it, though...
// No problem to use this.

(functio\u{6e} universalModuleDefinition(global, factory) {
    'use strict';

    // More readable with block statements.

    // I worry about precedence.
    if (('function' === typeof define) && define.amd) {
        define([exports], factory);
    }
    else if (exists('exports')) {
        factory(exports);
    }
    else {
        factory(global.classie = {});
    }

    // Check for variable declaration (independently of its value).
    // eval is better than Function# constructor since it evaluates a string
    // using the scope where it got called.

    function exists(IdentifierName) {
        try {
            return eval(IdentifierName), true;
        } catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

})(this, function factory(classie) {
    // classie = your exports (your library namespace, for example)
    'use strict';
});
```

Note: if you don't want to depend on the JavaScript interpreter to check variables declaration, I think the minimum solution is to check if it's not `undefined` (but a property/variable may also be `undefined`): `typeof variable !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: Yes i think all what you say here is correct and i has the same problem .. actually i need more time to check this

Comment: @ELHADRATI They made me post this, but sure